# Tags in comments have same style as normal links

Tags: discussion, tags, comments, hyperlinks

When I want to insert reference to a certain tag I use following syntax

```
[tag:tagname]
```

In posts tag looks like this [tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagname) and link looks like this [somelink](http://somelink).
But in comments both looks the same.

Am I supposed to format tags somehow differently in comments? Is it a problem only to me?

---

If I reference several tags and links in same post it looks ok. But if I try to do same in comments, then it's hard to distinguish between those and will definitely make my comment harder to read (compared to post).

An example (compare with comment below):

> Imagine I am talking about [thattag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thattag) and then telling you to read [somemanual](http://somemanual) and for [anothertag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anothertag) - [anothermanual](http://anothermanual). But then I talk about [thirdtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thirdtag) and give [multiple](http://multiple), [different](http://different), [links](http://links).

It looks good, try to do so in comments and you are lost, especially if my link names will match tag names.

Comment: I don't see what the [tag:problem] is. Comments don't have the same css formatting as posts do.

Comment: Could you explain why this is a problem for you?

Comment: Imagine I am talking about [tag:thattag] and then telling you to read [somemanual](http://somemanual) and for [tag:anothertag] - [anothermanual](http://anothermanual). But then I talk about [tag:thirdtag] and give [multiple](http://multiple), [different](http://different), [links](http://links).

Comment: @Sinatr Yes.  We're imagining it rather vividly at the moment.  What's the problem?

Comment: Comments are pretty cramped for the usual tag styling, that'd just end up messy. If you've got an idea to distinguish them without it looking awful you might consider turning this into a feature request, assuming there's not one already floating around.

Comment: Maybe I am formatting freak or something, but it **is** a problem to me and I've tried my best to explain it. I don't have a proposal to make it feature request, nor I think it's big enough to report it as a bug.

Comment: @Sinatr Just stating that it's a problem over and over again without stating *how* or *why* it's a problem isn't really helpful.  If you don't want to propose the feature be changed, then why are you posting at all?  What's the point of this question?

Comment: @Servy, when I read post and see tag there I know *it's tag*. I don't have to click it or inspect or anything. When I read comment I can't do the same, I have to either click it or inspect url in browser status bar. How is it useful "to know that it's a tag"? Well, I tried to mix several tags and links in comment and post to give an idea. Post looks better (easier to read and understand) than comment. Why? Because you can distinguish tags in post.

Comment: @Sinatr But even in your example it's clear what is an isn't a tag just from context, and even if you weren't sure, as you said, it's easy to check what the link is if you really want to be sure.  And that's with you actively trying to make it confusing.  Yes, there are less formatting options in comments than posts.  That's true for more than just tag formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Because comments have heavily constrained formatting allowances, you cannot rely on formatting alone to convey meaning in a comment.  You'll have to rely on sentence structure and context clues to do 99% of the work for you in this instance as opposed to formatting.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use all the tags available when editing post in comments, e.g. I can't insert an image or code block. But `[tag:name]` is available, same as italic, bold, hyperlinks..  And all of them looks different. Except tags, which looks and behaves identically to links. But they are not just links, they are .. different thing. I think you would complain if text in italic looks same as bold in comments ;) To me same appearance of tag is a problem.. maybe only to me.